# Creating a forward looking -match

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Playing around with PS and I have a simple script.

```
ipconfig /all | where-object {$_ -match "IPv4" -or  $_ -match "Description"}
```

This is great and does what i would expect. What I would like to do is read ahead and only show the description preceding the IPv4 line. Or reverse search and get the ipv4 and the next description then look for the next IPv4 etc.

Is there a way to do this without spinning through creating an array and then spinning through the array extricating the meaningful parts?

This command on my laptop results in:

```
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer Wireless-N 1103 Network Adapter
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred) 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.122.1(Preferred) 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.88.1(Preferred) 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
```

What I want is:

```
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer Wireless-N 1103 Network Adapter
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred) 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.122.1(Preferred) 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.88.1(Preferred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
[regex]$regex = '(?ms)^\s*(Description[^\r]+\r\n\s*IPv4[^\r]+)\r'
$regex.matches(((ipconfig /all) -match '^\s*Description|IPv4') -join "`r`n") |
foreach {$_.groups[1].value -replace '\. ',''}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract all Descriptions for IPv4 enabled adapters, you could try something like this:

```
ipconfig /all | Select-String "IPv4" -AllMatches -SimpleMatch -Context 5 | % {
    $_.Context.Precontext -match "Description" -replace 'Description(?:[^:]+):(.*)$', '$1'
}
    Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
```

To get it with your code, try this:

```
ipconfig /all | where-object {
    $_ -match "IPv4" -or  $_ -match "Description"
} | Select-String "IPv4" -SimpleMatch -AllMatches -Context 1 | % { 
    $_.context.precontext -replace 'Description(?:[^:]+):(.*)$', '$1'
}
```

**EDIT** Sorry, I misread your question earlier it seems. I thought you only wanted the description. This shows the description and IP lines for IPv4 active adapters

```
ipconfig /all | Select-String "IPv4" -AllMatches -SimpleMatch -Context 5 | % {
    $_.Context.Precontext -match "Description"
    $_.Line
}

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xx.xx.xx.xx(Preferred)
```

Comment: This displays the active adapters without the IPs which could be usefull as well. +1

Comment: I added another solution. I must have misread your question at first. Still, now you got some choices + an example of how to extract the description with regex (IP is done by replacing "Description" with "IP" and removing the dollar-sign in the regex) : )

Comment: This is a good alternative and with a different approach I have options as I make PS a relevant tool in 'my' toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which simply keeps track of the last description found in the output:

```powershell
switch -regex ( ipconfig /all ) { 'IPv4' { $d + $_ } 'Description' { $d = @($_) } }
```

Also, the [`-match` comparison operator](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113242) can work on an array as well as a single string. So using `(ipconfig /all) -match 'IPv4|Description'` is equivalent to the original `ipconfig /all | where { $_ -match 'IPv4' -or $_ -match 'Description' }` that checks each line individually.

Comment: +1 That this provides EXACTLY what I asked for in the original post. This is another approach that will help make PS relevant for me. I haven't used a switch in PS at all.